# Pass service values to template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to pass values of a service I created to a button template and insert that into my index.html. I wanted to have a reusable code to insert CRUD buttons.

Currently when I try to insert the buttons they appear without id, class and text, this is how they look "live".

[image]

This is what I have:

**Index:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="button.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div buttons></div>

  <div class="container"><div>version <strong><span app-version></span></strong></div></div>


  <script src="components/buttons/buttons.js"></script>
  <script src="components/buttons/buttons-service.js"></script>
  <script src="components/buttons/buttons-directive.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**ButtonJS**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.buttons', ['myApp.buttons.service','myApp.buttons.directive'])


.controller('BtnCtrl', ['$scope','buttonsService',function($scope,buttonsService) {
    $scope.buttons  = buttonsService.getButtons();
}]);
```

**ButtonService**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.buttons.service', [])

.service('buttonsService',function() {
  var buttons = [
               {type:"Add",color:"info"},
               {type:"Edit",color:"warning"},
               {type:"Delete",color:"danger"},             
              ];

  this.getButtons = function(){
      return buttons;
  };

});
```

**ButtonDirective**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.buttons.directive', [])

.directive('buttons', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            button: '=',
            buttonIndex: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/buttonTemplate.html'
    }
}]);
```

**ButtonTemplate**

```
        <div ng-controller="BtnCtrl" class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Actions</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >
<!--                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Button</button> 
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Button</button> -->
                        <button id="{{buttonIndex}}" class="btn btn-lg btn-{{button.color}}">{{button.type}}</button>
                        <button id="{{buttonIndex}}" class="btn btn-lg btn-{{button.color}}">{{button.type}}</button>
                        <button id="{{buttonIndex}}" class="btn btn-lg btn-{{button.color}}">{{button.type}}</button>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I am currently learning angular so I will keep reading the documentation, but each time I look one answer I end with more questions. If there is a simpler alternative I am open to try it, as long is not burning the values as it defeats the purpose of this excercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made several mistakes, I have corrected something, please look at this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UPvAelLus22NFGvicmYq?p=preview). Is it what you want?

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="docsTransclusionDirective">
  <div ng-controller="BtnCtrl" class="col-xs-12 text-center">
      <div buttons='buttons'></div>      
  </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsTransclusionDirective', [])
.factory('myService', function() {
  var buttons = [
               {type:"Add",color:"info"},
               {type:"Edit",color:"warning"},
               {type:"Delete",color:"danger"},             
              ];

  return function(){
      return buttons;
  };
})
  .controller('BtnCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
    $scope.buttons  = myService();
  }])
  .directive('buttons', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<table class="table">'+
                "<tr ng-repeat='but in buttons'>"+
                    "<td><input id='{{$index}}' type='button' ng-value='but.type' class='btn btn-lg btn-{{but.color}}'/></td>"+
                '</tr>'+
            '</table>',
        scope: {
            buttons: '=',
        },
    };
  });

})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `ButtonTemplate` you use two scopes. One is from controller and one is from directive. Controller knows what is `buttons`, directive knows what are `button` and `buttonIndex`, but there is no connection between any of those. I suggest you to delete scope in directive and in template use variable from controller (with ng-repeat):

```
<td ng-repeat="button in buttons">
    <button id="{{$index}}" class="btn btn-lg btn-{{button.color}}">{{button.type}}</button>
</td>
```